# checkbox no datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c# que faz impressão de etiquetas, para que isso ocorra eu uso um datagridview, que trás as linhas que preciso imprimir, agora preciso colocar um checkbox para selecionar a linha que preciso mandar para a impressora.

Preciso ter a opção de selecionar todas as linhas ou selecionar apenas uma linha só, estou com dificuldade pra criar esta condição dentro do meu código.

Segue o código que esta no botão de impressão.

```
private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (caixa_selecao.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        else
            EtqFraciona.PrinterSettings = caixa_selecao.PrinterSettings;
        etqfrac();
    }
}
```

codigo que carrega o datagridview

private void ListaGrid()
        {
            string strSQL = @"SELECT 
                            SC.C2_NUM AS GUIA,
                            SB.B1_DESC AS PRODUTO,
                            SC.C2_XNPAIS [PAÍS ORIGEM],
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST( SC.C2_XDTFAB AS DATE),103) AS [DT. FABRICAÇÃO],
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST( SC.C2_XDTVALI AS DATE),103) AS [DT. VALIDADE],
                            SC.C2_XLOTEF AS [LT. FABRICANTE],
                            SC.C2_XLOTE AS [LT. INTERNO],
                            SB.B1_XDCB AS DCB,
                            SB.B1_XCAS AS CAS,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SB.B1_PESO AS NUMERIC(15, 3))) + SB.B1_XSEGUM AS PESO,
                            SC.C2_XNOMFA AS FABRICANTE,
                            CB.CB0_CODETI AS [COD. BARRAS]
                       FROM SC2020 AS SC 
                       INNER JOIN SB1020 AS SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.B1_COD = SC.C2_PRODUTO
                       INNER JOIN CB0020 AS CB WITH (NOLOCK) ON CB.CB0_LOTE = SC.C2_XLOTE
                       WHERE C2_NUM = '" + txtGuiaFrac.Text + "'";

```
        comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conex);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            DGW_EtqFracionamento.DataSource = dtLista;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
        }

    }
```

Agora a coluna de checkbox no datagridview eu adicionei pelas propriedade do datagridview em add colunas.

Comment: Amigo, seria? WinForms? Asp.Net? seja mais especifico, vc quer colocar o `CheckBox` somente na impressão (report)? ou antes? e so imprimir oque vc estiver com  `Checked == true`?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, e windows form, mas não uso reportvierw não, uso o printdocument para fazer a impressão, só que não estou sabendo criar no datagridview o chekbox, se precisar coloco o restante do meu código.

Comment: amigo, vc quer fazer duas coisas diferentes, 1º  adicionar uma coluna ao `Grid`, acho que isso responde sua pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061103/how-to-add-the-checkbox-to-the-datagridview-from-coding 2º Imprimir somente oque for selecionado certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo Thomas, imprimir o que esta selecionado.

Comment: Thomas então se vc reparar na imagem acima na minha tela no campo selecionar eu adicionei o chekbox no datagridview so que não aparece o quadradinho pra fazer o tick.

Comment: coloca o codigo do gridview e do checkbox

Comment: Já coloquei o codigo do datagrideview, mas o codigo do chekbox não fiz porque ai esta minha dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta seguir esses passos, acredito que vai lhe ajudar.

- Seleciona o seu DataGridView dentro do Form.
- Selecione o Smart-Tag do DataGridView de acordo com a imagem.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Ao selecionar apareça as seguintes opções, selecione o que está marcado:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Irá aparecer uma nova janelinha de acordo com a imagem com todas as opções possíveis para você customizar o seu DataGridView. Já no seu é colocar um checkbox para cada opção. Aí você faz o seguinte, siga a sequência das imagens:

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Observe que existe as propriedades Name e Header Text.
**Name** - vai ser o NOME dado a coluna

### **Header Text** - vai ser o TITULO DA COLUNA que será exibido no DataGridView.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Pressione ADD**

Ao finalizar, você retornará a tela anterior, e a coluna que você criou. Se você selecionar a coluna você mudar a posição da coluna atráves das setas que se encontra no lado direito.

Por fim, pressione **OK**

E O SEU DATAGRIDVIEW FICARÁ COM O RESULTADO SIMILAR A ESSE:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok deu certinho aqui, muito obrigado.